# web page using dimplejs, x-tag, shows up fine in chrome and safari, blows up in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, dimple.js, x-tag

I have a strange problem and am not quite sure how to narrow the source of the bug (not a web developer).

A web page[1] which visualizes about 8 megs of data renders correctly on chrome and safari, but blows up on firefox (possibly IE as well). I'm using dimplejs visualization library, which is based on D3. I wrapped the dimple library in my custom created tags (created using x-tag/webcomponents) to remove chunks of imperative javascript.

Firefox shows only one of the 35 charts, and even that is extremely garbled. Further, firefox console shows "NS_ERROR_FAILURE: " error in the dimple library, but I can't find much information on that error (seems to be a catch all error).

I'm not clear on the error being in firefox, dimple, my x-tag implementation or some combination of all three. Dimple is not too popular yet and x-tag is extremely obscure, hard to find info on them. Forget about a solution, how can I find out which component/library is causing the problem?

[1]http://rule605.targetcompid.com/report.htm?mc=ALL&symbol=ALL&month=201409

Comment: Just for info, opening error console I receive 78 JS errors all related to incorrect path values, for example containing NaN, might be the same problem, I think you have a problem while receiving the data. The NS_ERROR_FAILURE normaly indicates that you have a XMLHttpRequest onerror handler in which you tried to read the result's status (or statusText) when that value is not available on the object.

Comment: @axel.michel I believe those errors are due to data d3 looking up values when they don't exist. Unexpected, zeroes, missing axis, etc. In other words, I believe those errors are just due to the nature of data.